# Hydra hangs after TASKS number of tries

Tags: password-cracking, hydra, dvwa

I have dvwa set up and i am using the command:

```
hydra -IV -t 1 -l admin -P rockyou.txt localhost http-get-form "/vulnerabilities/brute/index.php:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=Login:Username and/or password incorrect.:H=Cookie: PHPSESSID=tegnf0po32eavd385ckd9khqc3; security=low"
```

since my request in BurpSuite looks like this:

```
GET /vulnerabilities/brute/index.php?username=test&password=123&Login=Login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Referer: http://localhost/vulnerabilities/brute/index.php
Cookie: PHPSESSID=tegnf0po32eavd385ckd9khqc3; security=low
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

Hydra only tries one password and then hangs, only giving status updates for the next minutes like so:

```
[STATUS] 1.00 tries/min, 1 tries in 00:01h, 14344397 to do in 239073:18h, 1 active
[STATUS] 0.33 tries/min, 1 tries in 00:03h, 14344397 to do in 717219:52h, 1 active
```

My hydra version is v9.1

I am running DVWA in a docker container and can access the target page via browser on the url: `http://localhost/vulnerabilities/brute/index.php`

Comment: What happens when you increase the tasks number? Also, what is your question? If the problem goes away when you increase the number of tasks, this is not a security question.

Comment: The problem is that it does 1 try and stops not 1 try per minute as it should... Without the (-t) flag it just tries 16 times and then stops and keeps giving me updates with a reducing attempts/min number. My question was why hydra just stops doing attempts after TASKS attempts. It is a bug with my 9.1 version as I wrote in my answer... that is a waste of 3+ hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this issue: https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra/issues/612
Hydra 9.1 has a bug that affects that command... even though version 9.2 only says about an http-post-request buxfix

Kali does not install 9.2 version and says 9.1 is the latest when doing `sudo apt install hydra`